# python 2.7 script crashing ubuntu 16.04 : how to find reason?

Tags: python, debugging, crash, ubuntu-16.04, freeze

I run a complex python program that is computationally demanding.

While it is complex in terms of number of lines of code, the code itself is simple: it is not multi-thread, not multi-process and does not use any "external" library, with the exception of colorama, installed via pip.

The program does not require a big amount of memory.

When I run it, and monitor via "htop", it shows one (out of the eight) cpu is used 100% by the script, and around 1.16GB (out of 62.8GB) of memory are used (this number remains more or less steady).

After a while (10 to 20 minutes) of running the script, my ubuntu dell desktop running ubuntu 16.04 systematically freezes. I can move the mouse, but clicks do not work, the keyboard is unresponsive, and running programs (e.g. htop) freeze. I can only (hard) reboot. Note that the last frame displayed by htop does not show anything unexpected (e.g. no higher usage of memory).

I never experience such freezes when not running the python program.

I do nothing special in parallel of running the script, aside of browsing with firefox or dealing with mails using thunderbird (i.e. nothing that would use cpu or ram in a significative fashion).

I have printed traces in my python code: it never crashes at the same state.

I also print kernel logs in another terminal: nothing special is printed at the time of the freeze.

I do not use any IDE, and run the script directly from a terminal.

Searching for similar issue, it seems that they are usually related to overusage of memory, which does not seem to be my case.

I have no idea how to investigate this issue.

Comment: We need to see your complex python program.!

Comment: @RohitashwaNigam It's several thousands of lines of code across several modules. I am more asking for a systematic fashion of investigating such issues.